# How to run a command if a player is sitting in a tagged minecart?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to detect players that are sitting in minecarts that have been tagged with `/tag`, not ones without the tag.

I am playing in 1.15.2 Minecraft Java edition.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The NBT of a vehicle that you sit in is included in the "`RootVehicle`" tag of your player NBT. And since the NBT tag "`Tags`" is synchronised with the entity's tag list (from `/tag`), it's reachable that way.

So you can for example select yourself if you sit in a minecart tagged with "`a`" like this:

```
@s[nbt={RootVehicle:{Entity:{id:"minecraft:minecart",Tags:["a"]}}}]
```